# Is it possible to create an internal html page to my index.html?

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a new website and I will have different pages on it. However, instead of creating new HTML files for each page and an anchor for each, I want all my pages contained in one HTML file. Is it possible in any way?

Comment: you can try vue js ... which contains components.

Comment: Looks like you're talking about a [single page application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA), which there are many ways to accomplish depending on your needs.

Comment: Of course it's possible. You could just add elements to the HTML and hide them with CSS, then show them when a link is clicked. Have you done any research? Because I expect that there have been questions like this before...

Comment: Have you tried to consider the HTML <iframe> ?

Comment: I'm only familiar with Bootstrap at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Vue js or React js or many js frameworks ... which contain components.

**Using HTML**

You can control HTML page section how tabs working in HTML, take a look in Bootstrap Tabs, or you can **hide/show** sections using CSS or using JS, you may store HTML for each page in array of js and load that HTML to Body based on URL you create

**Using Server Side Language**

Also if you need single page application with multiple pages you need a Server Side language, where Database contains your website configurations and you can load based on the URL each page's layout or text like heading forms etc...